# Laravel 5.1 MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm using resource controller , when i submit form through ajax , it is showing method not allowed exception.

**View**

```
 {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'product.store','class' => 'form-horizontal','id' => 'productform','name' => 'productform','files' => true)) !!}
       {!! csrf_field() !!}
       <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 20px">
            <label for="productName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Product name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                 {!! Form::text('productName',null, array('id'=> 'productName','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Product name'))!!}
            </div>
       </div>                                                            
       <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                 {!! Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block')) !!}
            </div>
                </div>
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**AJAX**

```
$("#productform").submit(function () {
    var token = $('[name=_token]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'product/store',
        data: {
            id: '4',
            _token: token,
         },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            return false;
        }
    })
    return false;
});
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
```

What is the problem here...Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This error means a missing route and according to the routes.php you provided - the route is indeed missing. Your AJAX is hitting 'product/store', and your route is simply 'product'. Either modify the route or the url in AJAX

Comment: get the baseurl and add like this baseUrl + 'product/store'

Answer (score 0):

in jquery

```
var BASEURL = $("#baseURL").val()
```

in html

```html
<input type="hidden" id="baseURL" value="{{ url('') }}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

when you try to store data in laravel your URL must be.

```
url: 'product',
```

try to go on your CMD and type:

```
php artisan route:list
```

and check the URI of product.store Name then that will be you url in your AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

**in AJAX**

try to set url in AJAX to be route

```
$("#productform").submit(function () {
    var token = $('[name=_token]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{ route("product.store") }}',
        data: {
            id: '4',
            _token: token,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```